# Should I disable NUMA if my application is not NUMA-Aware

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, numa

Running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.  The application I'm running was not designed with NUMA in mind.  Would it be better to disable NUMA on my dual-socket system?  My guess is yes, but I wanted to confirm.  My server is a Westmere dual-socket system.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not multithreaded or is multithreaded but does not employ the threads to work simultaneously on the same problem (e.g. is not data parallel), then you can simply bind the program to one of the NUMA nodes. This can be done with various tools, e.g. with the "Set Affinity..." context menu command in Windows Task Manager. If your program is parallel, then you can still use half of the available process cores and bind to one NUMA node.

Note that remote memory accesses on Westmere systems are not that expensive - the latency is 1.6x higher than local access and the bandwidth is almost the same as the local on, therefore if you do a lot of processing on each memory value the impact would be minimal. On the other hand, disabling NUMA on such systems results in fine-mesh interleave of both NUMA domains which makes all applications perform equally bad as roughly 50% of all memory accesses will be local and 50% will be remote.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, turning NUMA on cannot harm the performance.

If your application is not NUMA aware, accesses will be managed by the OS, so might be across NUMA nodes or might be on the same one - depending on what other pressures the OS has, how much memory / CPU you're using, etc. The OS will try to get your data fast.

If you have it turned off, the OS doesn't know enough to even try to keep each application's execution CPU close to it's memory.

Comment: For sure it can harm performance in case if your application uses single huge pool of memory from several threads. Additionally, NUMA is more likely to cause swapping if one Node uses all allocated RAM (even if the others have some free RAM)

Comment: But doesn't that apply whether or not NUMA is enabled at the Operating System level?

Comment: I didn't try NUMA benchmarks, but looking at theory - NUMA doesn't honor memory shared between CPUs. And similarly - swapping may occur when all RAM is occupied on one of NUMA nodes, and other nodes have a lot of free memory.

Comment: Yes, but if the OS is not aware of NUMA, that happens anyway, only without the control of the operating system surely?

Comment: Not sure that I follow. With NUMA: RAM dedicated to single CPU is faster and shared RAM between CPUs is slower. The same with swapping: e.g. if single-CPU application tries to use more RAM than present in NUMA node, swapping may occur, (despite other NUMA Nodes have free RAM)

Comment: My (simplified here) understanding is that in a NUMA system, RAM located physically to CPU 0 will be used for processing on CPU 0 and RAM located physically near CPU 1 will be used for processing on CPU 1. If the Operating System knows nothing on NUMA, RAM that is physically close to CPU 0 could be used for processing on CPU 0 or CPU 1. So enabling NUMA on a system allows the OS to decide where to place data optimally, and disabling it means data will be placed ignoring the CPU being used.

Comment: Enabling or disabling NUMA doesn't physically move the RAM to a location equidistant from each CPU.